# How set style for library button

Tags: android, materialdrawer

I need set custom style for toggle button https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/fde00e5573310384b90d1f7f92d2b45c2ed8a2ba/library/src/main/res/layout/material_drawer_item_toggle.xml#L58 , but button is inside external library. How I can make it?

In my theme I add:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@drawable/btn_toggle</item>
```

And in btn_toggle.xml I add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/state_off"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_on"  />
</selector>
```

But toggleButton became invisible.

Comment: You have to replace the background with your own drawable.

Comment: Put your own `state_off.xml` and `state_on.xml` in the `drawable` folder

Comment: state_off and state_on is png icons in my drawable-.... folders. Why I need change them to *.xml?

Comment: You don't. I simply thought they were xml drawables. pngs are good as well.

Comment: Thanks, comment of Bhargav helps me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest implementation to get custom behavior inside the MaterialDrawer library is to create your own Custom DrawerItem.

Take a quick look at the `DividerDrawerItem` which is one of the simpler `DrawerItems` inside the project how you can do this.

In your case you want to modify the [ToggleDrawerItem](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/edit/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/model/ToggleDrawerItem.java). Just copy over the code and modify it to your needs.

```
public class ToggleDrawerItem extends BasePrimaryDrawerItem<ToggleDrawerItem> {
    private boolean toggleEnabled = true;

    private boolean checked = false;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener = null;

    public ToggleDrawerItem withChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        return this;
    }

    public ToggleDrawerItem withToggleEnabled(boolean toggleEnabled) {
        this.toggleEnabled = toggleEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public ToggleDrawerItem withOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public boolean isToggleEnabled() {
        return toggleEnabled;
    }

    public void setToggleEnabled(boolean toggleEnabled) {
        this.toggleEnabled = toggleEnabled;
    }

    public OnCheckedChangeListener getOnCheckedChangeListener() {
        return onCheckedChangeListener;
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
        this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "TOGGLE_ITEM";
    }

    @Override
    @LayoutRes
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.material_drawer_item_toggle;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        //get our viewHolder
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;

        //bind the basic view parts
        bindViewHelper((BaseViewHolder) holder);

        if (!isSelectable()) {
            viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (toggleEnabled) {
                        viewHolder.toggle.setChecked(!viewHolder.toggle.isChecked());
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        viewHolder.toggle.setChecked(checked);
        viewHolder.toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
        viewHolder.toggle.setEnabled(toggleEnabled);

        //call the onPostBindView method to trigger post bind view actions (like the listener to modify the item if required)
        onPostBindView(this, holder.itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderFactory getFactory() {
        return new ItemFactory();
    }

    public static class ItemFactory implements ViewHolderFactory<ViewHolder> {
        public ViewHolder factory(View v) {
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {
        private ToggleButton toggle;

        private ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.toggle = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.material_drawer_toggle);
        }
    }

    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            checked = isChecked;

            if (getOnCheckedChangeListener() != null) {
                getOnCheckedChangeListener().onCheckedChanged(ToggleDrawerItem.this, buttonView, isChecked);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

A more advanced but simpler solution is to add an `onPostBindView` listener to the item you want to modify and use the reference to the view to search for the `material_drawer_toggle`

```
(ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.material_drawer_toggle);
```

This will also allow your to modify and style this button as you need.